# Where is Claire's, Luca's, Cloche's, Frelia's and Mir's Install Ports?

Tags: ar-tonelico

I know that Aurica's is behind her neck, Misha's in just above her breasts and Shurelia's is above her butt (her words)

Despite Duelithnode Crystals being used for Installing than Gathnode Crystals in Metafalse Luca and Cloche would still have an Install Port for Life Extending Agents, likewise with Claire being a 3rd Generation Reyvateil. and since Shurelia has one i would assume Frelia and Mir have one aswell

So i am wondering where Claire's, Luca's, Cloche's, Frelia's and Mir's Install Ports are?

Answer (score 2):

Cloche has it on her armpits, and Luca has it on the higher part of her back, as shown in AT2 itself.
Mir has it above her navel, and Frelia has it in the same place as Shurelia. Claire's however, is unknown, and when someone asked her in the Toukousphere, she threatened to blast them with her song magic.